# How to detect fast touchesBegin events in SpriteKit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I am running a player animation based on touch events using the standard functions:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"TOUCH BEGINS*******");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"****TOUCH ENDS");

}
```

The problem is that a short gap between two touches on the screen fires the first TOUCH ENDS after the second TOUCH BEGINS causing inconsistency in actions.

How can I make the events be fired correctly?

Comment: You can not alter the order of events. If they sometimes occur in a different order your code has to be flexible enough to handle that case.

Comment: A workaround is to periodically check if a finger currently touches the screen. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Do you have any UIGestureRecognizers? UITapGestureRecognizer can prevent touchesEnded from being called.